# Ougoing telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Tags: 10.10, telnet

I am trying to telnet from Ubuntu server (running Maverick) on ec2 to another machine I have set up not on ec2 - we'll call it "server-x".  *Server-x is running an imap server and I am trying to test connectivity to it.*

The two machines are connected via vpn.  I can ping from the ec2 machine to server-x no problem.  On another machine also on the vpn but also not on ec2 I can telnet to server-x without issue so it is accepting incoming connections on that port.

But when I run telnet from the ubuntu instance to server-x I get :

```
ubuntu@ip-10-111-11-11:~$ telnet 5.1.1.1 9143
Trying 5.1.1.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Other telnets work like this:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-111-11-11:~$ telnet imap.gmail.com 993
Trying 173.194.76.108...
Connected to gmail-imap.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I have disabled ufw on the ubuntu machine.  Is there anything else that can be blocking this outgoing connection?  I tried adding the outgoing port to iptables but I'm not certain I'm doing that right.

**Update:**  The service running on server-x is an imap server.  When I changed it to use the traditional imap port 143 - the ubuntu machine can now telnet without problem.  Why can it not telnet out on 9143?

I'm pretty sure 9143 is open and listening on server-x, when I run netstat:

```
netstat -an |grep 9143    
tcp46      0      0  *.9143                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.9143                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 2):

*Connection refused*, apart from the port being blocked, may also mean that *nothing* is listening on that port (or that IP/interface).

Please run the following on the machine you are trying to telnet **to**:

```
netstat --numeric-ports -l | grep 9143
```

And paste the output as a comment, or edit it into your question. If you get no output, then there's a problem with whatever program is supposed to be listening on port 9143.

Comment: I've now changed the port the remote service is listening on and now it works.  See my update.

Comment: Was it listening on 9143 as shown by netstat? Anyway, glad it got solved :)

Comment: yeah it was, the remote machine is not linux, so I had to tweak my netstat but results the same